# Verify stability of the system

Tags: stability

A DT system is described as follows: 
$$y[n] = T(x[n]) = x[n] + \sum_{l=1}^\infty (0.9^l(x[n-l]+x[n+l])) $$

I have found that the Discrete-time necessary and sufficient condition for stability is.
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |h[n]| = ||h||_{1} < \infty $$

and in my case:

$ y(n) \le  B_{x} + \sum0.9^{L}(B_{x}+B_{x}) = B_{x} (1+2 \frac{2}{1-0.9} - 2) = 19B_{x} < \infty $

Is it enough to prove system stability?

Comment: What is $B_x$? If $|x[n]| < B_x, \forall n$ then yes.

Comment: It's just a conversion from the first equation. I'm not sure, maybe I could make a mistake, I did it similar way I was tough. If you can spot an error or anything extra I should add to prove it, just say.

Comment: @sswwqqaa conversion of *what* to $B_x$? $B_x=?$

Comment: I assume $ B_x = x(n)$?

Comment: @sswwqqaa In that case, the proof doesn't work.